# Display icons with text in toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

How can i display icons along with text in Bottom navigation of Android.
Many thanks!

[click here to view the image](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Jqn6dV7TAgq5jnjd9)

Comment: You should have an idea of what are you trying to do, and if you face an issue ask on Stack-overflow otherwise don’t ask those kind of questions 

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a `CardView` wrapping a `BottomNavigationView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_main"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/lorem"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_archive"
        android:title="Lorem"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ipsum"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_archive"
        android:title="Ipsum"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/dolor"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_archive"
        android:title="Dolor"/>

</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but in your solution the menu items look like group checkboxes, not like action bar menu items!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace icon from menu with your own png Icons heaving text. And will leave title remain empty. Its tested Technique!

Comment: this should be on comments

Comment: Its a solution As many people don't read comments thats why i answered! it can help many people to solve this problem. As i faced this problem and the above answer didn't worked for me.